# Firebase modular trying to use query in nested collections

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get data from a nested collection. When I create an appointment - I'm saving the appointmentId and doctorId in the current user. When I need them I take them from the user. And there is the big question - I creating appointments in firestore like this - appointments - [doctorId] (1) - currentDoctorApp - appointmentId - data
[part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvTuc.jpg) |
[part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0T37.png).
I know I can add data like normal - appointments - autoId - data, but I want to separate them, for a better search I think?

(1) - because I think if I have 50 doctors and the current user has appointmenthours at only 2, I will search in these 2 fields, not in all 50

This is the way I add it to appointments collection, but how can I get it? Еspecially when I get more than 1 doctorId. First I have to query by document id. I hope it's not very confusing

```
try {
        await setDoc(doc(db, `appointments/${params.doctorId}`, 'currentDoctorApp', generatedId), {
            doctorId: params.doctorId,
            userId: currentUser.uid,
            date: date,
            hour: hour,
            status: 'active',
            address: doctorData.hospitalAddres,
            hospital: doctorData.hospitalName
        });

        await updateDoc(doc(db, 'users', currentUser.uid), {
            appointments: arrayUnion({
                appointmentId: generatedId,
                doctorId: params.doctorId,
            })
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
```

Comment: Hi @BeginnerInIT, could please clarify what is your goal in this question? Please correct me if I'm wrong, as far as I understood your question, you would want to get the data from the `appointments` collection from the user and also get all its subcollection.  What specific data do you want to get? Could you please also include the data structure you want to achieve in your question for us to better understand what you want to get. Have you tried any query to get the data you want? If so, could you also please include it on your question.

Comment: Thank you for your response @MarcAnthonyB. You are right, I receive for example 2 ids from the `current user`, which ids are the same as one of the `doctors-id` and one of the `appointment-id` in the database. Every appointment for the current doctor is saved in appointments collection with his id. `https://prnt.sc/Lgu_OHhTcd5Y` and `https://prnt.sc/foumHrevx9lV`. I want to get the data from the appointments

Comment: Please don't post your question update as an answer as it will confuse the community that your question has been answered. Click on the edit, located below your question and put your question in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest changing your Firestore Data Structure to this:

```
doctors (collection)
 - documents (auto-id)
   fields (your-fields):
   - name
   - type

users (collection)
 - document (auto-id)
   - appointments (sub-collection)
     - documents (auto-id)
       fields:
       - address
       - date
       - doctorId
       - hospital
       - hour
       - status
```

If you use the above structure you can remove/delete your existing `appointments` collection and just refer to the user's sub-collection to avoid redundancy.
Here's a screenshots of Firestore Structure from above:

`users`:
[image]
`appointments` (sub-collection):
[image]

`doctors`:
[image]

To get all appointments from the users, you can query like this:

```
const doctors = collection(db, 'doctors');
const q = query(doctors, where("type", "==", "Psychiatrists"));
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  getUsersAppointment(doc.id);
});

async function getUsersAppointment(doctorId) {
  const appointments = query(collectionGroup(db, 'appointments'), where("doctorId", "==", doctorId), where("status", "==", "active"));
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(appointments);
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
  });
}
```

By using [**collectionGroup**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), you would be able to query its sub-collection but you need to configure the indexing first by following the prompt on the first run. The prompt should look like this:

```
[FirebaseError: The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/project-id/firestore/indexes?create_composite=ClZwcm9qZWN0cy90aXBoLW1hcmNhbnRob255Yi9kYXRhYmFzZXMvKGRlZmF1bHQpL2NvbGxlY3Rpb25Hcm91cHMvYXBwb2ludG1lbnRzL2luZGV4ZXMvXxACGgwKCGRvY3RvcklkEAEaCgoGc3RhdHVzEAEaDAoIX19uYW1lX18QAQ]
```

Create the index and wait for it to be enabled. The code above would result to:

```
9smR9t3ZU67CljVIzSbA  =>  {
  hour: '13:00',
  address: 'Test Address',
  doctorId: 'Zx2sWI2KZ3rJbPcUcUKu',
  hospital: 'MedEx',
  date: '2022-03-16',
  status: 'active'
}
```

You could also do it vice-versa by modifying the above data structure if you want it to call from the doctors and also logically reverse the code by querying the users first.